# Adding a raster data to an ArcGIS Online 3D Scene

Tags: raster, arcgis-online

How can I add a raster data to an ArcGIS Online 3D Scene ?
I have it in ArcGIS Pro, it already has the right projection (WGS84). I converted it to .kml. and was able to publish it to ArcGIS Online, but then either it is an image, or a feature that I can add to a 2D Map (depending on the format), but I am never able to import it to my 3D Scene.
What process would you suggest?